# Undefined symbols for architecture, tried i386 and other ,,,

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

just wanted to start some C++ and created these simple class:

Ellipsoid.h

```
#ifndef __Ellipsoid__Ellipsoid__
#define __Ellipsoid__Ellipsoid__

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>


class Ellipsoid {
private:
    double axisA;
    double flatteningF;

public:
    Ellipsoid() {};
   Ellipsoid(double aIn, double fIn);
    double getAxisA();
    double getFlatteningF();



};

#endif /* defined(__Ellipsoid__Ellipsoid__) */
```

Ellipsoid.cpp

```
#include "Ellipsoid.h"


Ellipsoid::Ellipsoid (double aIn, double fIn) : axisA(aIn), flatteningF(fIn) {};

int main() {
    std::cout << "bla";
    Ellipsoid el = Ellipsoid(44.3, 32);
    double test = el.getAxisA();


    return 0;
}
```

as you can see nothing special here. i'm using xcode on osx10.8.
But when i run the programm i come to this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Ellipsoid::getAxisA()", referenced from:
      _main in Ellipsoid.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
and i really can't figure out whats wrong. tried to set the architecture to 32 bit but this won't work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the `Ellipsoid::getAxisA()` function is missing. You must define somewhere. Right now you only have a declaration, not a definition. The definition could look something like this:

```
double Ellipsoid::getAxisA() { return axisA; }
```

And would live in Ellipsoid.cpp.

Comment: sure. mh, is there any way to get rid off the Ellipsoid:: at the beginning of each function?

Comment: The Ellipsoid:: stuff is only something you have to care about when defining the class, not when using it. So it shouldn't be that bothersome. If you really don't like it, you could define the functions inline in the class, but I don't like that, as it breaks encapsulation and makes compilation much slower. I haven't tested this, but perhaps a `namespace Ellipsoid { }` around the function definitions will work too.